# Having trouble accessing a field of a field if the first field is nil in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, foreign-keys

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I have a model that has a foreign key to a `users` table.

This is representative of my model:

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The `user` model has an `email` field.  In my view, how do I output the email field, given that not all objects will have a reference to the user model?  I tried

```
<td><%= my_object.user.email.present? %></td>
```

As is probably obvious, if the `user` field is `nil`, this produces this error:

> undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: All objects should have a user. This is what the belongs_to states..

Comment: Moreover, why having an empty record? The logic is having the user first. Then the object belonging to that user is created .. maybe you should rethink the linkage between the models ...

Comment: @Maxence, what is the syntax to use if the model is not always connected to a user, which is the case here?

Comment: Belongs_to can be used when there's a real dependency. Best example is when having 2 models:Articles and Comments. No points of having comments for a deleted article & comments can't be created if parent Article doesn't exist yet. In your case, there can't be any MyObject for a not existing user. We need more information to help you find out relationships. User and MyObject may just be independant.

Comment: If I remember well, you mention sailing or boats.. (your post seem edited). Let's assume MyObject is a boat. And sometimes a User want to rent a Boat. Then I would suggest creating a new model (called rentals for example) with fields such as User, Boat, Period of rental, etc... No new record from this model can have an empty User or Boat. Then there will be no empty record. You should read this page to understand better associations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html  (I am no specialist in that either)

Comment: Keeping with the boat analogy, let's say user is the owner.  A boat could have one owner or no owners.  If I have a boat, how do I find my way back to the owner in my boat model?  It seems wrong to create another model, "Ownership" that links boats to owners and then have the boat reference that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nil check to accomplish this:

```
<td><%= my_object.user ? my_object.user.email : "No user assigned" %></td>
```

This will check for the existence of the user before trying to access the email field.

Comment: Although the error goes away, this doesn't print anything out, even when users have an email address.  Coudl this have anything to do with the fact that in my table, I have a user_id reference, but in the code above we are using ".user"?

Comment: No, that won't be it.  The automatic syntax for `user` as a model object from `user_id` as an integer ID field is a benefit of using the Rails ActiveRecord Associations.  Since you have `belongs_to :user` in the `MyObject` model, this tells Rails that when it can find the associated User model object by navigating the `user_id`.

Comment: It's likely that your object is not associated with a user that has an email assigned.  There are 2 conditions checked for here: 1) a user is associated with the MyObject instance, and 2) the user has an email address.  If there's no user, it won't show anything (what you're seeing), and if there's no email, it would show "false".   You could change the `nil` in my answer to `"No User"` (with the quotes) and see if that shows up.

Comment: YOu're right.  There was no connection.  When I synced one up though, "my_object.user.email.present?" is printing out true/false.  Shouldn't it just be my_object.user.email ?

Comment: You can take out the `.present?` bit, and then it will show the email address.  I've updated my answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<td>
    <%= my_object.try(:user).try(:email).present? %>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a presenter.
Just make a plain Ruby object that will present your object in the views.

#### Presenter

```
class MyObjectPresenter
  attr_reader :my_object

  delegate :user, to: :my_object

  def initialize(my_object)
    @my_object = my_object
  end

  def user_email
    user.try(:email) if user
  end
end
```

#### Controller

```
def action
  @my_object = MyObjectPresenter.new(my_object)
end
```

#### View

```
<td><%= @my_object.user_email %></td>
```

#### Result

Dry models, views and controllers.

#### Note

If you have only one, two method calls in the view, all of this will be overkill.

Comment: Hi, In what directory does the presenter file belong?

Comment: In `app/presenters`. You can add this folder to your autoload path if you want.